# Should you book tickets in advance for the Ancona-Split ferries?

Tags: tickets, italy, ferries, croatia, mediterranean

I live in a city with many international ferries departing each and every day.

Here the prices changes all the time and you should book the tickets as soon as possible. Also the prices are different (much higher) if you're booking using the English/international version of the website.

However the prices I've seen for the Ancona-Split ferries seem pretty fixed (I've looked at SNAV and Jadrolinija). Are they not changing much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say no - the prices didn't seem to be changing at all for Jadrolinija.

But, if you want a specific date or cabin then you should book in time.

I don't know about SNAV since I haven't travelled with them.

---

*One could make some better research and actually check the differences.*